# Redirects in Next.js app on Digital Ocean not working and must use .html suffix for all pages

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean, jamstack

Is there a way to deploy a Next.js static site on Digital Ocean and get it to work "normally"?

I got an app deployed but every page has to be accessed via the .html suffix, and redirects specified in `next.js.config` don't seem to work. This breaks a lot of use-cases, and before I go back to Netlify, I wanted to make sure this isn't just a me problem.

I did follow the [guide here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-nextjs-deploy/) to generate a static site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export your Next.js site as static (as opposed to running it with node.js), you are serving static HTML, CSS and JS. That's why the redirects in `next.config.js` don't work.

To get those redirects working, there are multiple ways:

**1. Serving the Next.js site with node.js**

Next.js' all features including redirects will work if you run and serve it with node.js. How you can do is described in the ["Deploying Next.js as a Custom Server" section of the page you shared](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-nextjs-deploy/#deploying-nextjs-as-a-custom-server).

**2. Configuring your web server to handle the redirects**

Since you didn't share what you use as web server, I can't add any details. But for example, searching "nextjs nginx redirect" might help in case you are using nginx.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the generated files are in the form `locations/new-york.html` and so the `.html` extension is required for the CDN to locate the files. Fortunately there’s a configurable Next.js setting that turns these generated files into directories like `locations/new-york/index.html` which will allow you to use `site.com/locations/new-york` to access them.

To enable this option, add the following to `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Reference: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/next-js-static-site-requires-html-extension-in-url-for-dynamic-routes

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why this works, otherwise it may get deleted.